# Make is deleting my target. Why?

Tags: makefile

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html#Errors):

> Usually when a recipe line fails, if it has changed the target file
>   at all, the file is corrupted and cannot be used--or at least it is not
>   completely updated.  Yet the file's time stamp says that it is now up to
>   date, so the next time 'make' runs, it will not try to update that file.
>   The situation is just the same as when the shell is killed by a signal;
>   *note Interrupts::.  So generally the right thing to do is to delete the
>   target file if the recipe fails after beginning to change the file.
>   'make' will do this if '.DELETE_ON_ERROR' appears as a target.  This is
>   almost always what you want 'make' to do, but it is not historical
>   practice; so for compatibility, you must explicitly request it.

So, here I have a makefile:

```
# The idea here is to auto-generate the file ('make.include')
#    and to use it as a makefile.
# For simplicity, I replaced the "auto-generate" part, with "touch".
# I also simplified the dependency-tree with 'phony'.
#    In practice, we re-generate, only when "need" to.

make.include : phony
    +touch '$@'
    make -f '$@'

.PHONY: phony
```

Running:

```
$ make -q
```

I get:

```
touch 'make.include'
make: *** Deleting file 'make.include'
```

Now, i don't see how to prevent make from deleting this newly auto-generated 'make.include' (which may well be quite a costly process to re-run), unless i resort to the `.PRECIOUS` special target.

But, demanding the user to explicitly define their "precious" targets, is not in-line with that quote from the docs above. Right?

Answer (score 0):

This arises because of your use of `+` in `+touch '$@'` and executing `make` with the `-q` option. From the [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) the `-q` option is

> “Question mode”. Do not run any recipes, or print
>   anything; just return an exit status that is zero if the specified
>   targets are already up to date, one if any remaking is required, or
>   two if an error is encountered. See Instead of Executing Recipes.

The `+` symbol is only relevant when `make` is executed with the `-t`, `-n` or `-q` options and it tells make to execute any commands it precedes `make` is executed with any of the options `-t`, `-n` or `-q`. So, when you execute your current `makefile` with `make -q` you are asking `make` to check if everything is up to date without running any commands but because you've specified `+` before `touch '$@'` `make` must execute this command. To then leave everything the way it was before you executed `make -q` `make` must delete the file it created with `+touch '$@'`.

To answer your question specifically. If you don't want `make` to delete `make.include` then you can run `make` without the `-q` option on the `makefile` specified in your question.

However, the recipe for a target, i.e. `make.include` should not call its self with `make -f make.include`. It would probably be better to rewrite the `makefile` so that the recipe for `make.include` only creates `make.include` and it is then called with `make -f make.include` in another recipe.

```
make.include: 
    +touch $@

all: make.include
    make -f $<
```